# am_pm wrong im timepickerdialog

Tags: android, time, timepicker, android-timepicker

It is 5.30 PM on my mobile. (my default locale)

I do the following in my class and yet get an AM instead of PM.

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    private OnTimeSetListener listener;

    public TimePickerFragment(OnTimeSetListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(); 

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, c2.get(Calendar.HOUR), c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);
    }
}
```

However, this shows 5.30 AM instead of PM.

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    final Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, c2.get(Calendar.HOUR), c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE), c2.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
}
```

The value of c2.get(Calendar.AM_PM) = 0 for AM

The value of c2.get(Calendar.AM_PM) = 1 for PM

Comment: Anil, thanks for your effort. however, this did not work (as expected) because the TimePickerDialog takes the following parameters --  android.app.TimePickerDialog.TimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView)